# invalid literal for int() with base 10 while using session

Tags: python, django, session, django-views

I'm trying to send data from one view to another. I want to access the email throughout my application so, I'm setting email to session.
Now, I want to get object passing email as pk.

View where I set the session

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = get_object_or_404(UserDetails, pk=request.POST['email'])
        if(user.password==request.POST['password']):
            request.session['email']=user.email
            return redirect('/users/dashboard/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
```

View where I want to access the session value and use it to get the object

```
def profile(request):
    if(request.session['email'] is not None):
        user = get_object_or_404(UserDetails, pk=request.session['email'])
        userprofile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, pk=request.session['email'])
        return render(request, 'users/profile.html', {'user':user, 'profile':userprofile})
```

Model

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, primary_key=True, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mobile_num = models.IntegerField()
```

I am getting this invalid literal for int() with base 10 error at my email value.This might be a question asked many times but, I did not find any solution to it.Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: given the auth middleware includes the user in the request anyway... why do you need to do this? doesn't `request.user.email` acheive the same thing?

Comment: I'm not using the default login and authentication which django provides

Comment: Is `email` the primary key field of your user model? I kinda doubt it...

Comment: Yes, my model is here lass UserDetails(models.Model):
 email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, primary_key=True, blank=False)
 name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
 password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 mobile_num = models.IntegerField()